# WPF - Resizing Column/Row aligment

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, resize, alignment

I want to create a List-view in WPF (2) which doesn't change the spacing between the columns and row when re-sizing, but automatically changes the column count to fit.

What i have:

[image]

What i want

[image]

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
    Title="Test1" Height="800" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF000000" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Width="200" Height="300" Stretch="Fill" DataContext="{DynamicResource Image}" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                </Border>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{DynamicResource Data}" Source="{Binding Status}" Height="100"/>                    
            </Grid>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="0,81,0,0">
    <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Name="View" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = DataList}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This looks like effect of [`WrapPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx). Have you tried to assign it as `ItemsPanelTemplate`?

Comment: If i assign `WarpPanel` to `ItemsPanelTemplate` it works but it only shows one row or column, not both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution, i changed this:

```
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

to this:

```
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>                 
                <UniformGrid  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Columns="3"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: Does 4th column shows up when you resizing? I am curious, because you specify `Columns=3` explicitly.